# How to create a master file in android

Tags: android

How to create a master file in android so that all the data will be provided in that file itself saving the memory. I want to store all the data from different activities in one activity itself.

I have many gif animations used in many different activities, So i want to reduce the coding of all the activities and write it only once in a single activity and pass different gif files in different activities.

Comment: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write MasterActivity that extends Activity and add the stuff you want to use in all other activites. 
And after that your all other activities should extend this MasterActivity and the work will be done.

```
public class MasterActivity extends Activity{
     // Some Common Stuff
}

public class Activity1 extends MasterActivity{

}
```

It should look something like this.

Comment: yes but how should i pass the parameters from master activity, as the parameters will differ in each activity. suppose I am using gif files in every activity, how can i pass its parameters? This is the code.. GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
    (this, "file:///android_asset/abc.gif"); setContentView(view);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data from all activities in one  class [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class is the only way. You can extend the Application class and make say it in your manifest

```
 <application
        android:name="com.example.app.YourApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity....
```

Then have some data in it

```
public class YourApplication extends Application 
{     
     public SomeDataClass data = new SomeDataClass();
}
```

and you will get access to the data from every `Activities`. You can get the application class  from any activity using [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29).

Comment: suppose the back button exist on every activity, I want to store the coding of back button on one activity itself and retrieve the data whenever the user clicks on the back button of ANY activity.